# Laravel mail queue break cyrillic sender's name encode

Tags: php, laravel, email, environment-variables, queue

The problem is that when I send an email synchronously everything works fine.

```
Mail::to(env("MAIL_TO"))->send(new MortgageApplication($validatedReqest['name'], $validatedReqest['phone']));
```

[image]

then i use the mail queue, cyrillic string in env return incomprehensible value.

```
Mail::to(env("MAIL_TO"))->queue(new MortgageApplication($validatedReqest['name'], $validatedReqest['phone']));
```

get the sender's name like this
[image]

I found what was the problem. Then i use env variables in MortgageApplication class and send without queue this work fine.

```
public function build()
{
    var_dump(env('MAIL_FROM_NAME'));
    var_dump(mb_detect_encoding(env('MAIL_FROM_NAME')));
    return
        $this->subject('test')
        ->from(env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'), env('MAIL_FROM_NAME'))
        ->view('mortgage-application')
        ->with([
            'name' => $this->name,
            'phone' => $this->phone,
        ]);
}
```

And `env('MAIL_FROM_NAME')` return needed string
`mb_detect_encoding(env('MAIL_FROM_NAME'))` return 'UTF-8'

If i use queue env variables breaks.

And `env('MAIL_FROM_NAME')` return ���� �� ��������  `mb_detect_encoding(env('MAIL_FROM_NAME'))` return NULL

Why env return incomprehensible value when mail send in queue. And how can solve the issue?

Temporary solution : put env variables in MortgageApplication constructor

```
Mail::to(env("MAIL_TO"))->queue(new MortgageApplication($validatedReqest['name'], $validatedReqest['phone'], [
            'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME'),
            'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS')
        ]));
```

MortgageApplication class

```
public function build()
{

    return
        $this->subject('test')
        ->from($this->from['address'], $this->from['name'])
        ->view('mortgage-application')
        ->with([
            'name' => $this->name,
            'phone' => $this->phone,
        ]);
}
```